# How to check that Image is already exist or not on given path in GWT + MVP4G

Tags: image, gwt, mvp4g

I want to check if the Image exists or not on the fileSystem.  I am using GWT 2.4 with the  MVP4G framework.  When I use IO.File on the client side to check file.exist(), it gives me an error because we cant use IO on client side, so How can I check this..?

Answer (score 0):

How did you get the image?
The only way you should get the image is by using some file upload mechanism and any one of those will only let the user choose an already existing file; so there is actually no need to check for the file existence.
For file upload you can use the gwt library gwtupload. or use apache File Upload library.